# when button pressed change images on background on activity in android

Tags: android, button, android-activity, background

i want to make two buttons next and previous that changes different images by image id when i pressed butoon on same activity. how to make it im beginner in android programming please help

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because your font name has a space in it. Try renaming the font to something along the lines of `komikaaxis` all lowercase, then change all of your code to have the font be lowercase and no space in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial should answer your question on custom fonts and Corona SDK:

http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/01/16/faq-wednesday-custom-fonts/

Basically the name you use inside the quotes has to match the internal font name of the font, and it's helpful to have that filename of the font match the internal font name of the font.